# How do I select which radio tag the user has selected in my javascript folder

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the code in my showresults function to select the users answers (which would be the input tag that the user has selected as the answer to each quiz question) and comparing it to the correct answer in my questions array but whenever I do this the submit button doesn't work and I am also not sure if I should put this code in my nextquestion function or my showresults function.

this is my script file

```
const questiontext= document.getElementById('question-text');
const A= document.getElementById('OptionA');
const B= document.getElementById('OptionB');
const C= document.getElementById('OptionC');
const D= document.getElementById('OptionD');
const nextbutton= document.getElementById('next');
const resultcontainer= document.getElementById('results');
const submitbutton= document.getElementById('submit');
const options= document.querySelectorAll('options');
const questions=[
    {
        question: "What is the best item at mcdonalds?",
        answerA: "Fries",
        answerB: "Big Mac",
        answerC: "Mcnuggets",
        answerD: "Quarter Pounder",
        correctanswer: "Big Mac"
    },
    {
        question: "What is the cheapest thing on the mcdonalds menu?",
        answerA: "Fries",
        answerB: "Double Cheeseburger",
        answerC: "Happy Meal",
        answerD: "Orange juice",
        correctanswer: "Fries"
    },
    {
        question: "What is the least popular item at mcdonalds?",
        answerA: "Filet O Fish",
        answerB: "Hamburger",
        answerC: "Veggie Deluxe",
        answerD: "Mineral water",
        correctanswer: "Filet O Fish"
    },
    {
        question: "How many dips are you allowed with 20 Mcnuggets?",
        answerA: "2",
        answerB: "4",
        answerC: "3",
        answerD: "6",
        correctanswer: "4"
    }
];
//Question index at start
let questionindex= 0;
//Before they have answered any question
let numcorrect=0;
const currentquestion= () =>{
    questiontext.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].question;
    A.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerA;
    B.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerB;
    C.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerC;
    D.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerD;
}
const nextquestion= () =>{
    currentquestion();
    questionindex++
    if(questionindex === questions.length){
        submitbutton.classList.remove('hidden');
        nextbutton.classList.add('hidden'); 
     }
}
const showresults= () =>{
    if(options.checked===questions[questionindex].correctanswer){
        numcorrect++
    }
    resultcontainer.innerHTML=`You got ${numcorrect} out of ${questions.length}`;
}
//Load first question and answers
currentquestion();
//Button to display next question
nextbutton.addEventListener('click', nextquestion);
submitbutton.addEventListener('click', showresults);
```

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fast food facts</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="quizcontainer">
            <div id="quiz">
                <div id="question"><h2 id="question-text"></h2></div>
                <div id="answers">
                    <label for="A" id="OptionA"></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option" id="A" class="options">
                    
                    <label for="B" id="OptionB"></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option" id="B" class="options">
                    
                    <label for="C" id="OptionC"></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option" id="C" class="options">
                    
                    <label for="D" id="OptionD"></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option" id="D" class="options">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="submit" class="hidden">Submit</button>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <script src="static/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your comparison on submit.

First, you were not targeting the radio inputs because there was a missing dot in the selector:

```
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");  // Added a dot to specify a class
```

Then, to each radio, I added a `value` using the `currentquestion` function.

```
A.nextElementSibling.value = questions[questionindex].answerA;
```

Finally, I had all that is needed to do a comparison in `showresults`. A loop was necessary to go through each radio:

```
// Loop through the radio inputs to compare its value if checked
options.forEach(function(option){
  if(option.checked && option.value === questions[questionindex].correctanswer){
    console.log("Correct anser found!")
    numcorrect++;
  }
})
```

```js
const questiontext = document.getElementById("question-text");
const A = document.getElementById("OptionA");
const B = document.getElementById("OptionB");
const C = document.getElementById("OptionC");
const D = document.getElementById("OptionD");
const nextbutton = document.getElementById("next");
const resultcontainer = document.getElementById("results");
const submitbutton = document.getElementById("submit");
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options"); // Added a dot to specify a class
const questions = [
  {
    question: "What is the best item at mcdonalds?",
    answerA: "Fries",
    answerB: "Big Mac",
    answerC: "Mcnuggets",
    answerD: "Quarter Pounder",
    correctanswer: "Big Mac"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the cheapest thing on the mcdonalds menu?",
    answerA: "Fries",
    answerB: "Double Cheeseburger",
    answerC: "Happy Meal",
    answerD: "Orange juice",
    correctanswer: "Fries"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the least popular item at mcdonalds?",
    answerA: "Filet O Fish",
    answerB: "Hamburger",
    answerC: "Veggie Deluxe",
    answerD: "Mineral water",
    correctanswer: "Filet O Fish"
  },
  {
    question: "How many dips are you allowed with 20 Mcnuggets?",
    answerA: "2",
    answerB: "4",
    answerC: "3",
    answerD: "6",
    correctanswer: "4"
  }
];
//Question index at start
let questionindex = 0;
//Before they have answered any question
let numcorrect = 0;
const currentquestion = () => {
  questiontext.innerHTML = questions[questionindex].question;
  A.innerHTML = questions[questionindex].answerA;
  A.nextElementSibling.value = questions[questionindex].answerA;
  B.innerHTML = questions[questionindex].answerB;
  B.nextElementSibling.value = questions[questionindex].answerB;
  C.innerHTML = questions[questionindex].answerC;
  C.nextElementSibling.value = questions[questionindex].answerC;
  D.innerHTML = questions[questionindex].answerD;
  D.nextElementSibling.value = questions[questionindex].answerD;
};
const nextquestion = () => {
  currentquestion();
  questionindex++;
  if (questionindex === questions.length) {
    submitbutton.classList.remove("hidden");
    nextbutton.classList.add("hidden");
  }
};
const showresults = () => {
  // Loop through the radio inputs to compare its value if checked
  options.forEach(function (option) {
    if (
      option.checked &&
      option.value === questions[questionindex].correctanswer
    ) {
      console.log("Correct anser found!");
      numcorrect++;
    }
  });

  resultcontainer.innerHTML = `You got ${numcorrect} out of ${questions.length}`;
};
//Load first question and answers
currentquestion();
//Button to display next question
nextbutton.addEventListener("click", nextquestion);
submitbutton.addEventListener("click", showresults);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fast food facts</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="quizcontainer">
    <div id="quiz">
      <div id="question">
        <h2 id="question-text"></h2>
      </div>
      <div id="answers">
        <label for="A" id="OptionA"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="A" class="options">

        <label for="B" id="OptionB"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="B" class="options">

        <label for="C" id="OptionC"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="C" class="options">

        <label for="D" id="OptionD"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="D" class="options">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="submit" class="hidden">Submit</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script src="static/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ive ran through this snippet of code and it doesn't seem to work unfortunately, it says that it cannot read properties of undefined correct answer.

Comment: it also says that index is declared but never read

Comment: I agree about the unused `index` in the `options.forEach` loop. I edited. But about the other issue, I can't tell. You have to do some minimal debugging yourself.